# Using strftime on nil object - how to prevent error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strftime

I use strftime to format my raw time as the text of an input box. Usually, when I use strftime I check if the object is nil to prevent errors by using unless nil? However it doesn't seem like I can use that here:

```
<%= text_field_tag :event_date, @event.event_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p"), :size=>30 %>
```

I removed the unless because it was throwing an error. How can I make sure this statement works if @event.event_date is nil?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One trick is to use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

```
<%= text_field_tag :event_date, @event.event_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p"), :size=>30 %>
```

Or just check if `event_date` is set:

```
<%= text_field_tag :event_date, (@event.event_date && @event.event_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %I:%M%p")), :size=>30 %>
```

Comment: Would this also be a good candidate for `.blank?` I've been working in some forms recently and it's come in handy. (Since it checks for an empty string and nil.)

Comment: or if you want to use rails date formats: @event.event_date.try(:to_formatted_s, :long)